# What open source C projects are worth studying for learning good design?

Tags: c, open-source

What small open source projects in C are interesting for learning good design?

The project should be:

- Not too large (like the linux kernel)
- Well documented
- Perhaps still under active development

I've just started learning C, and while the language itself is not too difficult, i'm struggling how to design larger applications, so i thought checking out other open source projects would be a good starting point.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learn C from Open Source code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144568/learn-c-from-open-source-code)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In my opinion, good examples of moderately sized projects written in C are:

- [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) (besides the source code, don't miss their [design document](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/design/gsl-design.html))
- [Kazlib](http://www.kylheku.com/~kaz/kazlib.html)
- [Git](http://git-scm.com/)

Comment: Thanks! Found someone visiting Kazlib in my Apache logs, with this question as the referrer. :)

Comment: GNU Scientific Library, seems to be a quite good lib to learn, not only c, but also math & algorithm

Answer (score 26):

Redis (nosql db) is:

- under active development
- a manageable size
- portable and robust
- has no external dependancies
- very well written, understandable code

Comment: +1!This is a beautiful answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Posix threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) are a perfect example of good C design

Answer (score 2):

I like gnucash: http://www.gnucash.org/

No too large like Linux kernel, but still big I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can start learning from small and well structured applications like http://abygaelle.guillaume-fr.net/trac/gemmes

Answer (score 1):

It all depends what kind of projects you are interested in. And what aspect of it (specific algorithms, UI, networking, etc, etc...)

Head over to freshmeat, sourceforge or ohloh and browse the projects for your area of interest.

Alternatively if you want to look at projects that were chosen for a particular reason google summer of code might be interesting for you - even though these rarely include full projects.

EDIT:
Also alternatively, you might take something like linux kernel, but instead of trying to understand everything try to

- get the big picture
- then concentrate on one tiny piece of it and inspect how the code changed over time (and for what reasons - it should be quite well documented)